# como apuntar scroll a un contenedor

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Tengo una tabla que carga cierta cantidad de documentos con sus respectivos datos ocultos,
al darle click se muestra los datos.
Asi que lo que quiero es que el documento que se seleccione se muestre centrado en el contenedor, osea que el scroll se ajuste de manera visual, que muestre los datos del documento seleccionado.

Para lo cual tengo el nombre de cada documento en un thead y sus respectivos datos están en un tbody  ocultos. La cantidad de datos de cada documento son variables, asi que lo que quiero es que el thead donde esta el nombre del documento seleccionado, se ajuste en la parte superior y sus datos continuo.

Para lo cual yo use el siguiente código, pero no pude hacerlo funcionar como quiero. Quisiera una ayuda con esto por favor, gracias.

```
$(".table_fix_yope").animate({
    scrollTop: $("#" + valor).prop("scrollHeight")
}, 1000);
```

Este es un código ejemplo que tengo para probar.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<style> 
    .table_fix_yope { overflow: auto; height: 320px;}
    .table_fix_yope thead th { position: sticky;top: -1px;}
</style>
<body>

<div class="container">
<div class="table_fix_yope">
  <table class="table table-bordered">
     <thead>
      <tr class="success">
        <th>#</th>
        <th colspan="2" class="text-center">Documentos Entregados</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <thead>
      <tr class="success">
        <td>#</td>
        <td colspan="2" class="acordeon_yope" value="tbody_docu_1">Documento 1</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tbody_docu_1" hidden="true">
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Nombre</td>
        <td>aaa</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Nombre</td>
        <td>bbb</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Nombre</td>
        <td>ccc</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Nombre</td>
        <td>ddd</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <thead>
      <tr class="success">
        <td>#</td>
        <td colspan="2" class="acordeon_yope" value="tbody_docu_2">Documento 2</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tbody_docu_2" hidden="true">
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Nombre</td>
        <td>aaa</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Nombre</td>
        <td>bbb</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <thead>
      <tr class="success">
        <td>#</td>
        <td colspan="2" class="acordeon_yope" value="tbody_docu_3">Documento 3</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tbody_docu_3" hidden="true">
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Nombre</td>
        <td>aaa</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Nombre</td>
        <td>bbb</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Nombre</td>
        <td>ccc</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <thead>
      <tr class="success">
        <td>#</td>
        <td colspan="2" class="acordeon_yope" value="tbody_docu_4">Documento 4</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tbody_docu_4" hidden="true">
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Nombre</td>
        <td>aaa</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Nombre</td>
        <td>bbb</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Nombre</td>
        <td>ccc</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Nombre</td>
        <td>ddd</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Nombre</td>
        <td>eee</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <thead>
      <tr class="success">
        <td>#</td>
        <td colspan="2" class="acordeon_yope" value="tbody_docu_5">Documento 5</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tbody_docu_5" hidden="true">
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Nombre</td>
        <td>aaa</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Nombre</td>
        <td>bbb</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Nombre</td>
        <td>ccc</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Nombre</td>
        <td>ddd</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Nombre</td>
        <td>eee</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
</div>
<script>
$(".acordeon_yope").click(function () {
    var valor = $(this).attr("value");
    if ($("#" + valor).is(":visible")) {
        //--Ocultar
        $("#" + valor).hide();
    } else {
        //--Mostrar
        $("#" + valor).show();
        //--Este es el codigo que uso para tratar de ajustarlo
        $(".table_fix_yope").animate({
            scrollTop: $("#" + valor).prop("scrollHeight")
        }, 1000);
    }
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: O sea que cuando aparezcan los datos ocultos la pagina haga un scroll directo a esa ubicación?, o sea a la etiqueta donde aparecen

Answer (score 0):

Puedes ocupar la función [scrollIntoView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView)

```js
   $(".acordeon_yope").click(function () {
    var valor = $(this).attr("value");
    if ($("#" + valor).is(":visible")) {
        $("#" + valor).hide();
    } else {
        $("#" + valor).show();
       document.getElementById(valor).scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"});
    }
});
```

```css
.table_fix_yope {
    overflow: auto;
    height: 320px;
    
}
tbody {
    scroll-margin-top: 26px;
}
    .table_fix_yope thead th {
        position: sticky;
        top: -1px;
        
    }
.container{
    height:100px;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
<div class="table_fix_yope">
  <table class="table table-bordered">
     <thead>
      <tr class="success">
        <th>#</th>
        <th colspan="2" class="text-center">Documentos Entregados</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <thead>
      <tr class="success">
        <td>#</td>
        <td colspan="2" class="acordeon_yope" value="tbody_docu_1">Documento 1</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tbody_docu_1" hidden="true">
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Nombre</td>
        <td>aaa</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Nombre</td>
        <td>bbb</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Nombre</td>
        <td>ccc</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Nombre</td>
        <td>ddd</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <thead>
      <tr class="success">
        <td>#</td>
        <td colspan="2" class="acordeon_yope" value="tbody_docu_2">Documento 2</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tbody_docu_2" hidden="true">
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Nombre</td>
        <td>aaa</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Nombre</td>
        <td>bbb</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <thead>
      <tr class="success">
        <td>#</td>
        <td colspan="2" class="acordeon_yope" value="tbody_docu_3">Documento 3</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tbody_docu_3" hidden="true">
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Nombre</td>
        <td>aaa</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Nombre</td>
        <td>bbb</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Nombre</td>
        <td>ccc</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <thead>
      <tr class="success">
        <td>#</td>
        <td colspan="2" class="acordeon_yope" value="tbody_docu_4">Documento 4</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tbody_docu_4" hidden="true">
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Nombre</td>
        <td>aaa</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Nombre</td>
        <td>bbb</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Nombre</td>
        <td>ccc</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Nombre</td>
        <td>ddd</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Nombre</td>
        <td>eee</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <thead>
      <tr class="success">
        <td>#</td>
        <td colspan="2" class="acordeon_yope" value="tbody_docu_5">Documento 5</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tbody_docu_5" hidden="true">
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Nombre</td>
        <td>aaa</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Nombre</td>
        <td>bbb</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Nombre</td>
        <td>ccc</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Nombre</td>
        <td>ddd</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Nombre</td>
        <td>eee</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
</div>
```